# How to generate RTFs with PHP

Tags: php, rtf

I need to generate an RTF from within PHP. I've seen several libraries out there but wondering if anyone has used any of them or if they've just hand coded their own (which I'm perfectly able to do). Any opinions out there? TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I've used **PhpRtf** and it was very good. You can download it at http://sourceforge.net/projects/phprtf/

Comment: I used that library too. A must.

Answer (score 0):

bz-htmlcss2rtf please try with this.

http://joseluisbz.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/working-rtf-html-css-and-script-files-with-my-own-packages-java-and-php/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bzhtmlcss2rtf/